# Como puedo guardar la imagen de un lector de huella en Mysql?

Tags: java

*Me gustaría guardar la imagen , (NO el template) de una imagen de lector de huella el código para convertirla según el manual de DigitalPersona es este:*

```
public Image CrearImagenHuella(DPFPSample sample) 
{
 return 
DPFPGlobal.getSampleConversionFactory().createImage(sample);
}
```

*Y el codigo que uso para guardar en Mysql es este:*

```
try 
{   
     Connection c=cn.conectar();
     PreparedStatement guardarStmt = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO somhue(hnombre,identificacion, huehuella) values(?,?,?)");
     guardarStmt.setString(1,nombre);
     guardarStmt.setInt(2, Id);
     guardarStmt.setBinaryStream(3,in);
     //Ejecuta la sentencia
     guardarStmt.execute();
     guardarStmt.close();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Huella Guardada Correctamente");
     cn.desconectar();
     BtnGuardar.setEnabled(false);

}
 catch (SQLException ex)
{
     //Si ocurre un error lo indica en la consola
     System.err.println("Error al guardar los datos de la huella.");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La persona ya se encuentra registrada por favor verificar los datos e intentar de nuevo ","VERIFICACION DE DATOS", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

}
finally
{
cn.desconectar();

}
```

*Sin embargo no he podido usar esa variable "sample" dentro del código para guardar en mysql, alguien que pueda indicarme como poder almacenarla?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setBinaryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) requiere en el segundo parámetro un objeto de tipo `InputStream`

Pero lo que tienes es un objeto de tipo `Image`, como el código no es completo supongo que `java.awt.Image`

Si el objeto del que dispones fuese de tipo `BufferedImage` sería sencillo convertirlo a un stream de bytes :

```
Image imagen = CrearImagenHuella(sample);
BufferedImage buffImg = convertirABufferedImage( imagen );
ByteArrayOutputStream streamWrite = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image,"png", streamWrite); // Puede que quieras otro formato distinto
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(streamWrite.toByteArray());

/// ... Y ya puedes usar .....

guardarStmt.setBinaryStream(3,in);
```

Ya solo falta convertir la imagen a Buffered image, lo cual he sacado de esta [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605411/956880) de [Sri Harsha Chilakapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026805/sri-harsha-chilakapati)

```
/**
 * Convierte una imagen en BufferedImage
 *
 * @param img La Image a convertir
 * @return El BufferedImage convertido
 */
public static BufferedImage convertirABufferedImage(Image img)
{
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
    {
        return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    // Crear imagen buffered con transparencia
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Dibujar la imagen en la buffered imagen
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Devolver la buffered image
    return bimage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Gracias a [la respuesta de Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21518/127), pude resolverlo. Publico la solución final en caso de que a algún usuario le sirva.

En este caso por medio de `BufferedImage` hice lo siguiente:

1. Declare una variable llamada `Ejemplo`

   ```
   private DPFPCapture Lector = DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();

   private DPFPEnrollment Reclutador = DPFPGlobal.getEnrollmentFactory().createEnrollment();

   private DPFPVerification Verificador = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();

   private DPFPTemplate template;

   public BufferedImage Ejemplo;
   ```
2. Luego a esta variable le asigne `image`, que es la que me dibuja el lector.

   ```
   Image image=CrearImagenHuella(sample);
   DibujarHuella(image);
   Ejemplo =  (BufferedImage) image;
   ```
3. Dentro del método `Guardar` tengo el siguiente código:

   ```
   public void guardarHuella(DPFPSample sample)
       {
       try
        {

         //Obtiene los datos del template de la huella actual

         String formato = "JPEG";

         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         if(Ejemplo !=null)

          ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) Ejemplo, formato, out);
           DibujarHuella1( Ejemplo);

         InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
         ByteArrayInputStream datosHuella = new ByteArrayInputStream(template.serialize());
         Integer tamañoHuella=template.serialize().length;

         //Pregunta el nombre de la persona a la cual corresponde dicha huella
         String nombre;
         String Identificacion;
         nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre:");
         Identificacion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"NUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION:"+"\n" +"NO colocar puntos ni guiones","DATOS PERSONALES",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         //se creó la variable tipo entero llamada Id
         int Id;
         //Convierte la variable Identificacion la cual esta de tipo String a entero por medio de la variable Id
         Id =Integer.parseInt(Identificacion);
           {
             try
           {                    
                 //Establece los valores para la sentencia SQL
                 Connection c=cn.conectar();
                 PreparedStatement guardarStmt = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO somhue(hnombre,identificacion, huehuella) values(?,?,?)");
                 guardarStmt.setString(1,nombre);
                 guardarStmt.setInt(2, Id);
                 guardarStmt.setBinaryStream(3,in);
                 //Ejecuta la sentencia
                 guardarStmt.execute();
                 guardarStmt.close();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Huella Guardada Correctamente");
                 cn.desconectar();
                 BtnGuardar.setEnabled(false);

                 }
              catch (SQLException ex) 
                {
                 //Si ocurre un error lo indica en la consola
                 System.err.println("Error al guardar los datos de la huella.");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La persona ya se encuentra registrada por favor verificar los datos e intentar de nuevo ","VERIFICACION DE DATOS", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     
             }
             finally
             {
                 cn.desconectar();   
             }      
         }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Huella.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      }
   ```

Y al final cuando coloque la visualización en el label, ya pude ver la imagen de la huella y almacenarla en la base de datos. Esta pesa 60KB lo cual no es mucho.

Comment: @Mariano Ok... estoy borrando mi comentario anterior

Comment: Buen día jorge, ¿tendrás las librerías?, voy a trabajar con un U.are.U 4500 y necesito guardar registros de personal que trabaja en la empresa. saludos.

Comment: Buenas noches Jorge Herrera, estoy trabajando un sistema con lector de huella, ya tengo la parte de leer la huella, pero no he podido guardar, vi tu aporte y está muy bien solo en esta parte no se a dónde envía DibujarHuella1( Ejemplo); y también que si me puedes ayudar con el BtnGuardar.